# Reading in specific data from a text file

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to read in specific data from the text file `10-10-1CNT_pot.pot_fmt`. The data needed is `a`,`b` and `c` as well as the `fft coefficients` (25,300,300) in this case. Currently the only way I can think of to read these in, is from their position in the text file. I do not like this however as it is prone to bugs if the text file changes slightly. Can anyone suggest an alternate method?

Please see an example text file below (and the buggy code):

```
BEGIN header

       Real Lattice(A)               Lattice parameters(A)    Cell Angles
   2.4675850   0.0000000   0.0000000     a =    2.467585  alpha =   90.000000
   0.0000000  30.0000000   0.0000000     b =   30.000000  beta  =   90.000000
   0.0000000   0.0000000  30.0000000     c =   30.000000  gamma =   90.000000

 1                            ! nspins
25   300   300                ! fine FFT grid along <a,b,c>
END header: data is "<a b c> pot" in units of Hartrees
```

Code:

```
file = open("10-10-1CNT_pot.pot_fmt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()


parts = lines[3].split() 
a = parts[5]

parts1 = lines[4].split() 
b = parts1[5]

parts2 = lines[5].split()
c = parts2[5]

parts3 = lines[8].split()
width = parts3[0]

parts4 = lines[8].split()
height = parts4[1]

parts5 = lines[8].split()
depth = parts5[2]
```

Comment: Do you just want read (a,b,c) value ?

Comment: Yes, and the three integers that appears before the string "! fine FFT grid along <a,b,c>"

Comment: What you have done so far? post your code.

Comment: Have done this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use regex so :

```
import re


s=""

with open('your_file_name','r') as myfile: 
 a = myfile.readlines()

for i in a:
 s +=i

list1=list()

list2=list()



list1.append(re.findall('(a = .* ) alpha | (b = .* ) beta | (c = .* ) gamma', s ,re.M))



list2.append(re.findall('(.*) !',s))
for i in list2:

 print i[1]

for i in list1 :
 for j in i:
  print j[0],j[1],j[2]
```

output:

```
25   300   300    

a =    2.467585   
 b =   30.000000  
  c =   30.000000
```

Comment: do you want this result ? i also can edit my solution please say any bug

Comment: Thank you! My one issue is that the numbers in the file change therefore the string stored in s will change. Will this cause a problem?

Comment: now if any parameter get changed in file you also can get your results

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!